# use instance property as v-model

Tags: vue.js

I use a `Form` object to handle all my input fields and validation/errors etc.

```
new Vue({
el: '#root',
data: {
    form: { trainer: '' }
}
```

And I can use it as `v-model` like this:

```
<input v-model='form.trainer' name='trainer'>
```

I would like to make the `form` an instance property, because I have to pass it to all my components at the moment.

```
Vue.prototype.$form = {trainer: ''}
new Vue({ el: '#root' });
```

However, its not reactive anymore:

```
<input v-model="$form.trainer">
<span v-text="$form.trainer"></span>
```

Changes to the input are not reflected on the span.

Is there a solution to use a instance property as v-model?

Comment: maybe a mixin would be better? I would have suggested vuex but not sure how you'd do it with declarative rendering

Comment: @A.L need to read about mixins thanks for he hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Global Mixin:**

You can use Global Mixin and then add `form: { trainer: '' }` to it and then this option will be available in every Vue instance created afterwards like:

```
// inject a handler for `myOption` custom option
Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      form: { trainer: '' }
    }
  }
})
```

and then you can use it like normal component `data` option:

```
<input v-model="form.trainer">
<span v-text="form.trainer"></span>
```

**Demo:**

```js
// inject a handler for `myOption` custom option
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      form: { trainer: '' }
    }
  }
})

// Define a new component called trainer
Vue.component('trainer', {
  template: `<div>
    <input v-model="form.trainer">
    <span v-text="form.trainer"></span>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <trainer></trainer>
  <trainer></trainer>
</div>
```

**Demo #2:**

```js
var trainer2Data = {
  form: { trainer: '' }
}

Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return trainer2Data;
  }
})

// Define a new component called trainer2
Vue.component('trainer2', {
  template: `<div>
    <input v-model="form.trainer">
    <span v-text="form.trainer"></span>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <trainer2></trainer2>
  <trainer2></trainer2>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that all `<trainer>` components point to the same `form.trainer` value? Your solutions makes it reactive, but its not an instance property anymore.

Comment: You mean like if you change any one trainer component input, it should update all trainer components model and text values?

Comment: @palash yes exactly

Comment: I have added a 2nd demo related to this. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you that is fantastic. Although I have no idea why the first and second solution have different results.

Comment: I figured it out, it was just a scope thing that confused me. Still thanks for the link

Comment: Glad you were able to get the concept finally. JS can be quite tricky when dealing with array and objects.